# Bootstrap 3: How to get two form inputs on one line and other inputs on individual lines?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I trying to format my registration page with Bootstrap 3.1.1.  I would like the first two inputs to be on the same line while the other inputs are one there own line.  I have played around with the bootstrap classes "row", "form-inline", and "form-horizontal" to no avail.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/E3Mz9/)

```
<style>
.reg_name {
 max-width:200px;
}
</style>


<form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname"
                   title="Enter first name"
                   placeholder="First name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname"
                   title="Enter last name"
                   placeholder="Last name"/>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" autocapitalize='off' name="username"
               title="Enter username"
               placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password"
               title="Enter password"
               placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `<div class="row">` and `<div class="form-group col-xs-6">`

Here a fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/core972/SMkZV/2/

Comment: Remember not to make the width (n) too big in col-xs-_n_, otherwise the fields will wrap on to the next line regardless. The defaults that came with MVC edit templates were `col-md-10`, and no matter what I did the field would not stay on the same line until I reduced the size. F12 CSS browser helped me troubleshoot

Comment: Hai, Can anyone tell me if 'col-xs' will automatically set the same rules for the smaller devices as well?

Answer (score 18):

You can wrap the inputs in `col-*` classes

```
<form name="registration_form" id="registration_form" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
             <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
             <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name">
           </div>       
           <div class="col-sm-6">
             <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
             <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name">
           </div>
    </div><!--/form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label for="username" class="sr-only"></label>
          <input id="username" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" autocapitalize="off" name="username" title="Enter username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div><!--/form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div><!--/form-group-->
 </form>
```

http://bootply.com/127825

Comment: I liked this solution but say I need the first name and last name to be `col-lg-6` and `col-xs-12`. When it goes to `xs, sm, md` there is not margin on top and bottom and it looks all wonky. Any ideas?

Comment: Wrapping everything inside `col-*` without using a parent element with a class `row` will cause the element to have `padding-left` and `padding-right`.

Comment: @Barrosy yes, that's true for newer Bootstrap 4.x, *but* when this question was **answered for Bootstrap 3.x** the `.form-horizontal .form-group` had the negative margin just like the `.row`, therefore `.row` was not necessary at that time.

Answer (score 11):

**You can code like two input box inside one div**

```
<div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input style="width:50% " class="form-control " placeholder="first name"  name="firstname" type="text" />
            <input style="width:50% " class="form-control " placeholder="lastname"  name="lastname" type="text" />
        </div>
```

Comment: This was the most appropriate answer for me. It allows the textboxes to squeeze up to each other instead of being spaced on the bootstrap grid like the other answers

Answer (score 1):

I resorted to creating 2 style cascades using inline-block for input that pretty much override the field:

```
.input-sm {
    height: 2.1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and a series of fixed sizes as opposed to %

```
.input-10 {
    width: 10em;
}

.input-32 {
    width: 32em;
}
```