# Rails and Bootstrap 3: How to get first and last name on same line?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been unable to get First and Last name fields on the same line, and at half the width of the other lines - email, password, etc.

I have tried various changes to including the addition of "form-horizonal", col-xs-6, but didn't solve it.

I would like to make the well look like this (currently the are all the same sized, stacked on top of each other):

[image]

Excerpt of index.html.erb:

```
<form class="form-signin col-sm-4 well" role="form">
          <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr>

          <form class="form-inline" role="form">

            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <label class="sr-only" for="#">First name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <label class="sr-only" for="#">Last name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
            </form>


            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type email again">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
          </form>
        </form>
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Full index.html.erb - 
https://gist.github.com/attatae/11022245

Bootstrap 3 Grid Overview (yes, I looked too): 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Another related question that I looked at, but didn't solve:
[Bootstrap 3: How to get two form inputs on one line and other inputs on individual lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888298/bootstrap-3-how-to-get-two-form-inputs-on-one-line-and-other-inputs-on-individu)

Comment: In the picture of how you would like it to look, there are no labels for first and last name. Would you like yours to not have the labels as well?

Comment: @lennon625, if you refer to something like `<%= f.label :first_name %>`, then it's fine if there is nothing besides the placeholder. I only need the placeholder to let people know where to put name and such.

Comment: Right. I'm working on a fiddle right now, but for starters, remove the labels (<label>First Name: </label>) for both of those inputs, otherwise it won't line up the way you would like it to. After that it will be just a matter of giving the first and last name inputs an id so that they can be targeted with CSS, and floating them to the left. I'll have a fiddle for you momentarily to show you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is what I came up with](http://jsbin.com/leqox/1/edit?html,css,output)

I hasten to add that the solution may be different because of the fact that it's bootstrap. My solution doesnt take that into consideration at all, because I'm not familiar with it. It may be as easy as changing some of the classes. Good luck to you...