# Multiple form-groups on single row in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-4

Does anyone know if this kind of thing is possible?

I've tried using inline-group and form-inline but then it doesn't seem to conform to fit the full grid width.

Whereas form-horizontal seems to expect the entire form on one row.

This code creates the desired output (two form controls on one row) but form-groups are required around each one for viewing in sm mode.

NB: This is for a 16 col grid.

```
<form>
    <div className="form-group row">
        <!--form group needed here -->
        <label className="col-form-label col-md-2" htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">First Name*</label>
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" />
        </div>

        <!--form group needed here -->
        <label className="offset-md-2 col-form-label col-md-2" htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">Last Name*</label>
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't think this is a duplicate of:
[Bootstrap 3: How to get two form inputs on one line and other inputs on individual lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888298/bootstrap-3-how-to-get-two-form-inputs-on-one-line-and-other-inputs-on-individu)

...because this isn't leaving me with full control of grid columns within via form labels etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: How to get two form inputs on one line and other inputs on individual lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888298/bootstrap-3-how-to-get-two-form-inputs-on-one-line-and-other-inputs-on-individu) The question about form inputs, but solution about form groups.

Comment: Can't seem to get any control of columns using that approach 

Answer (score 5):

Place your form-groups into `.col-*` containers to align the groups in a horizontal layout, for example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

If controls of a form group should be aligned in a horizontal layout too, use [`.form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) class for the form. In this case `.form-group`s behaves as grid `row`s. Thus, it is possible to apply [Nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) template for your form:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I just hadn't understood nested rows properly:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#nesting

This works fine:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-md-4" for="formGroupExampleInput">First Name*</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="offset-md-2 col-form-label col-md-4" for="formGroupExampleInput">Last Name*</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input" />
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this what @Alexander suggested in his answer?

Comment: Hi ganders, it seems, to me, that the desired result is possible with either approach.  (With or without 'form-horizontal'.)