# Change position of inputs in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm using squarespaceModal to have a modal containing a form who looks like that :

[image]

I would like to have first two inputs (name and firstname) on the same line.

This is the actual CSS code :

```
   .center {
    margin-top:50px;   
}

.modal-header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
        padding: 0;
    }

.modal-footer .btn-group button {
    height:40px;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.modal-footer .btn-group:last-child > button {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

the target is to void the scroll down.

Comment: use `col-md-6` bootstrap class to both of your inputs.

Comment: put 2 rows into `.col-md-6` both for example. More here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: How to get two form inputs on one line and other inputs on individual lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888298/bootstrap-3-how-to-get-two-form-inputs-on-one-line-and-other-inputs-on-individu)

Comment: Please share your `HTML` code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
label, input {
  display: block; /*inputs are styled as block */
}
<style>
```

Hope this help you